# Axios not sending headers, request failing, getting 401 error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I've been fetching some data from a private API with `axios`, but now I'm having a problem fetching data from one specific endpoint.

The interesting thing is that with the built in `fetch` API, I'm receiving 200 response, but the identical request with `axios` keeps retuning 401 error. Any idea what can be the problem?

This code works:

```
const upVoteCommentTwo = async () => {
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("access_token"));
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://exammple.com/comments/${commentId}/vote/up`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "X-API-KEY": "XXX",
          "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
        },
      }
    );

    console.log(await response.status);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

And this does not work:

```
const upVoteCommentOne = async () => {
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("access_token"));
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      `https://example.com/comments/${commentId}/vote/up/`,
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "X-API-KEY": "XXX",
          "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
        },
      }
    );

    console.log(response.status);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is coming from `axios`'s parameters. One valid way, according to the [doc](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro) and that seems to be working for most people according to this [issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/891) on GitHub is to call it like below, with an object:

```js
const response = await axios({
  method: "post",
  url: `https://example.com/comments/${commentId}/vote/up/`,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-API-KEY": "XXX",
    "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
  },
  data: {/* Your Data Goes Here */},
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const upVoteCommentOne = async () => {
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("access_token"));
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
          `https://example.com/comments/${commentId}/vote/up/`,
         {
           //body:...if any
         }
        headers: {
          "X-API-KEY": "XXX",
          "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
        },
      }
    );

    console.log(response.status);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: pls explain. Just catch the error doesn't mean if helps OP