# axios doesn't set custom header

Tags: typescript, axios

I have my `http` class which uses axios, and it has a method for setting authorization token into headers:

```
export class Http {
  constructor(private readonly _axios: AxiosInstance) {
    this.useInterceptors();
  }

  setAuthorizationHeader(token: string): void {
    this._axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }

  unsetAuthorizationHeader(): void {
    delete this._axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
  }

  private useInterceptors(): void {
    this._axios.interceptors.response.use(
      undefined,
      (error: AxiosError): Promise<AxiosError> => {
        if (error.response?.status === 401) {
          store.dispatch(actions.auth.signOut());
        }
        return Promise.reject(error.response?.data);
      },
    );
  }

  get get() {
    return this._axios.get;
  }

  get post() {
    return this._axios.post;
  }

  get put() {
    return this._axios.put;
  }

  get patch() {
    return this._axios.patch;
  }

  get delete() {
    return this._axios.delete;
  }

  get request() {
    return this._axios.request;
  }

  get axios(): AxiosInstance {
    return this._axios;
  }
}

export const http = new Http(
  axios.create({
    baseURL: API_URL,
    timeout: 60000,
  }),
);
```

also I have my middleware for authorization:

```
export const authMiddleware =
  () =>
  (next: Dispatch) =>
  (action: AnyAction): AnyAction => {
    if (action.type === 'client/code/fulfilled') {
      action.payload?.token &&
        http.setAuthorizationHeader(action.payload.token);
    }

    if (action.type === REHYDRATE) {
      action.payload?.auth?.token &&
        http.setAuthorizationHeader(action.payload.auth.token);
    }

    if (action.type === actions.auth.signOut.type) {
      http.unsetAuthorizationHeader();
    }

    return next(action);
  };
```

And I have a problem, when I `console.log` axios common headers I don't see there `Authorization`. What could be a cause of this?

Comment: add log statements when you set/unset the Authorization header in the Http class. This will give you a better idea of whats happening.

Comment: @Francisco Garcia I did it. This methods calls, and I had a also get token there, but when I trying `console.log('headers', axios.defaults.headers.common);`, a still don't see my `Authorization` header. Also I added log into my unset method and it dons calls.

Comment: Do you log before your actions fire? Also, check that you are logging the headers in the appropriate axios instance (use the instance passed to your Http class)

Comment: @Francisco Garcia it works, i used log inside my http class, and there is my custom header

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Axios not sending headers, post request failing, getting 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72343387/axios-not-sending-headers-post-request-failing-getting-401)

Comment: @yousoumar no, the problem was that I logged base axios, but not my Http class instance