# how can i send token to backend i n vue js

Tags: javascript, axios

i'm trying to make payment to my backend, but each time i send the payment i get this message from my backend

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "No token Provided"
}
```

my backend requires authentication

this is my script tag

```
 methods: {
    sendTokenToServer(charge, response) {
      const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
      axios
        .post(`http://localhost:5000/api/pay`, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer" + token,
            "x-access-token": token
          },
          totalPrice: this.getCartTotalPriceWithShipping,  
        })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

when i check my dev tool i see my token

```
token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ"
```

this is my backend headers

```
 let token = req.headers["x-access-token"] || req.headers["authorization"];
```

please how can i go about this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Axios not sending headers, request failing, getting 401 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72343387/axios-not-sending-headers-request-failing-getting-401-error)

Comment: Did you look at the answer given there? The above thread.

Comment: @yousoumar getting the same response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code looks fine, just create an object then add it to the url i guess your looking for something like this.. try this

```
methods: {
    sendTokenToServer(charge, response) {
 var request = {
        totalPrice: this.getCartTotalPriceWithShipping,
      };
      const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
      axios
        .post(`http://localhost:5000/api/pay`,request, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer" + token,
            "x-access-token": token
          },
        })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
        });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

*First* parameter is your url,

*Second* parameter is your data,

*Third* parameters is your config.

You can make a post request like below

```
axios
  .post(
    `http://localhost:5000/api/pay`, 
    data,
    {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}` //mind the space before your token
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "x-access-token": token,
      }
    }
  );
```

NOTE: data is your request body.

e.x.

```
{
  "firstname": "Firat",
  "lastname": "Keler"
}
```

Comment: still getting same error, what should be in (data)

Comment: It's your request body, a javascript object

Comment: What is x-access-token?

Comment: that's the token i from the backend, the answer didn't work...updated the question to

Comment: I do not know how you handle it in the backend but I have included that too in my axios post request updating my answer again

Comment: same response i'm getting

Comment: What does your intellisense of your IDE show you when you type 'axios.post(' ? Which parameters in which orders?