# How to implement JWT authentication from ASP.NET Core Web API to Vue.js SPA?

Tags: vue.js, rest, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I made Vue.js single page application for using almost 10-15 API's which are written in ASP.NET Core Web API by me. I would like to use JWT authentication with this project. However I don't have any idea about how should I implement JWT authentication.

On backend side I store token, `passwordHash` and `passwordSalt` in `User.cs` model (I mean, I store in database). Then I created JWT token in controller which does register and login operations. After that I did some configuring in program.cs and tried authentication by Swagger, it works! Actually on backend side everything is okay.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Surname { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    public string? Gender { get; set; }
    public string? Token { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime CreatingDate { get; set; }

    public string? BioText { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Friendship> Friendships { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Content> Contents { get; set; }
}

[ApiController]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    private IUserService _service;
    private IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public AuthController(IMapper mapper, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _service = new UserManager();
        _mapper = mapper;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    [HttpPost("register")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<User>> Register(UserAuthDto request)
    {
        CreatePasswordHash(request.Password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt);
        User user = _mapper.Map<User>(request);
        user.Username = request.Username;
        user.PasswordHash= passwordHash;
        user.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;

        _service.CreateUser(user);
        
        return Ok(user);
    }

    [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> Login(UserAuthDto request)
    {
        User user = _service.GetAllUsers()
                            .Where(x => x.Username == request.Username)
                            .FirstOrDefault();
        
        if (user == null) 
        {
            return BadRequest("User not found.");
        }
        else
        {
            if(!VerifyPasswordHash(request.Password, user.PasswordSalt, user.PasswordHash))
            {
                return BadRequest("Wrong Password.");
            }
            else
            {
                string token = CreateToken(user);
                user.Token = token;
                return Ok(token);
            }
        }
    }

    private void CreatePasswordHash(string password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt) 
    {
        using(var hmac = new HMACSHA512())
        {
            passwordSalt = hmac.Key;
            passwordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
        }
    }

    private bool VerifyPasswordHash(string password, byte[] passwordSalt, byte[] passwordHash)
    {
        using(var hmac = new HMACSHA512(passwordSalt))
        {
            var computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((string)password));
            return computedHash.SequenceEqual(passwordHash);
        }
    }

    private string CreateToken(User user) 
    {
        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username),
        };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));

        var cred = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);
        
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            claims: claims,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            signingCredentials: cred);

        var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

        return jwt;
    }
}
```

The problem is I don't know how can I use token on frontend side. I mean should I use it in body of every requests or doesn't backend need anymore token? I am open to ideas I need your help, thank you.

Comment: In JWT authentication, for the first login request, API validates user credentials that are received from the UI app (Vue js). Once validated, you create a new JWT token from user claims (id, email, roles) using a secret key. UI application (Vue js) will receive that JWT token and store that token on the UI side (local storage). For each subsequent request, the JWT token will be sent in Authorization Headers (Authorizations: Bear your_token) and API will validate that token. The token can have a lifespan of 1 hour, once the token is expired a new one will be requested from UI app.

Comment: @DeepakSinghNegi thanks for precious informations. You said that "For each subsequent request, the JWT token will be sent in Authorization Headers and API will validate that token.".  Well should I add "Authorizations: Bear token" to  header of every requests manually or does add automatically? Thank you again 

Comment: "For each subsequent request", I meant protected API calls that actually need that token. You will need to add that token in the header manually.  Please check this question to send token from vue js [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73294570/how-can-i-send-token-to-backend-i-n-vue-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73294570/how-can-i-send-token-to-backend-i-n-vue-js)

Comment: @DeepakSinghNegi Now I get it clearly. Thanks for your attention.  