# Axios delete not working in react js with Authorization token

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to run a delete query with react js. In Postman my delete query is working, but in my code it says no Authorization

I did

```
console.log(headers)
```

to check if header is available but still it's not working. I have posted what I have tried

```
const deletefile = (e) => {
    const headers = {
      Authorization: `Token ${sessionStorage.getItem("token")}`,
    };
    console.log(headers);
    const Data = {
      id: e,
      //   // stage: "stage9",
      //   notes: notes,
    };
    axios
      .delete("file/", Data, {
        headers: headers,
      })

      .then(() => {
        alert("success submited");
        // setRefresh(Refresh + 1);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
      });
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: does this have a value `sessionStorage.getItem("token")` and can you show how did you test in postman (may be a screenshot) ?

Comment: @KcH i have updted the question with screen shot

Comment: @KcH console.log(headers); i am getiing the token here

Comment: this is not helpful tbh, need a screen shot headers, where token gets passed

Comment: @KcH do u want screen shot of the browsers console.tab?

Comment: so `token` is `Token` ... check that as first step :)

Comment: yes i tryed both token and Token no luck

Comment: also what is `id : e` `e` is an event ... to get `id` just check ....

Comment: e has the id 1 that if i console.log(e) i get 1

Comment: u can see in scrreen shot id is required to delete each row

Comment: and shouldn't it be as ... .`delete("file/", {data: Data}, {
        headers: headers,
      })` ?

Comment: @KcH still getting no token error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247704/discussion-between-kch-and-menu-cd).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Axios not sending headers, request failing, getting 401 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72343387/axios-not-sending-headers-request-failing-getting-401-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the headers as so :)

```
   axios
    .delete("your_url", {
      headers: headers,
      data: Data
    })
```