# Error 401 Unauthorized in Axios in React JS

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I was trying to post a comment through Axios. But I am getting the 401 error, even though I have passed the header with the Authorization token. I don't know what is causing this error.
Please Help . My boss is yelling at me :) (I am a junior developer).

```
const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const finalComment = { comment };

        try {
            const response = await axios.post(
                `${TEST_API_URL}/user/proposal/comments/admin/create`,
                finalComment,
                {
                    withCredentials: true,
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`,
                    },
                }
            )
            console.log(response);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
}
```

Comment: I hope you are missing Bearer.
401 is a Unauthorized credential error
If you have access token, then you can put this in header.
headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accesstoken}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Axios not sending headers, request failing, getting 401 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72343387/axios-not-sending-headers-request-failing-getting-401-error)

Comment: It's not working. Can it be a server problem?